# What is wrong with this my codes and its working

Tags: php, html

i want to use this code to fecth the selection of the usear and use for some further calculation but it aint working:

my codes are as below

**html codes**

```
<select class="form-control"  name="currency">
    <option     value="default">Bitcoin(USD)</option>
    <option value="gcr">GCR(USD)</option>
    <option value="perfect money">Perfect Money(USD)</option>
    <option value="club coin">Club Coin(USD)</option>
</select>
```

*php codes*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo 'success';
$currency = $_POST["currency"];

switch($currency){
    case 'Bit coin(USD)':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'Perfect Money(USD)':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'GCR(USD)':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'club coin':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
}
}

if(isset($_POST['usd']) && !empty($_POST['usd'])){
    $usd = $_POST['usd'];
    $total = $usd * $fixed_price;
    echo $total . "GHS";
}else if(isset($_POST['ghs']) && !empty($_POST['ghs'])){
    $usd = $_POST['ghs'];
    $total = $usd * $fixed_price;
    echo $total . "USD";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this codes worked for me

**html codes**

```
                               <div id="calculator"> 
                                    <h3>Calculator</h3>
                                    <form class="form-horizontal"  action="index.php" method="POST" role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                            <label for="sel1">Select E-currency:</label>
                                            <select class="form-control"  name="currency" style="width:35%;margin-left:210px;">
                                                <option value="default">Bitcoin(USD)</option>
                                                <option value="gcr">GCR(USD)</option>
                                                <option value="perfect money">Perfect Money(USD)</option>
                                                <option value="club coin">Club Coin(USD)</option>
                                            </select><br><br>

                                            <div class="row">
                                               <h3>From USD To GH&cent;</h3>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">                                                        
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" name="usd" placeholder="USD">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-2">                                                        
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" placeholder="=>" disabled>
                                                </div>      
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info">GH&cent;</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <h3>From GH&cent; To USD</h3>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">                                                        
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" name="ghs" placeholder="GHS">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-2">                                                        
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" placeholder="=>" disabled>
                                                </div>      
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">                                                        
                                                    <button class="btn btn-info">USD</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;">Convert</button>
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                         <div id="results">
                                        <?php include 'includes/calculator.php'; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

**php codes**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['currency'])){

$currency = $_POST["currency"];

switch($currency){
case 'default':
$fixed_price = 4.30;
break;
case 'perfect money':
$fixed_price = 4.30;
break;
case 'gcr':
$fixed_price = 4.30;
break;
case 'club coin':
$fixed_price = 4.30;
break;
}

if(isset($_POST['usd']) && !empty($_POST['usd'])){
    $usd = $_POST['usd'];
    $total = $usd * $fixed_price;
    echo '<hr width="50px">'. $total . "GH&cent;";

}else if(isset($_POST['ghs']) && !empty($_POST['ghs'])){
    $usd = $_POST['ghs'];
    $total = $usd * $fixed_price;
    echo '<hr width="50px">'. $total . "USD";
}


}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your switch, you should not get the text of the options, but the value, try this:

```
switch($currency){
    case 'default':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'perfect money':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'gcr':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
    case 'club coin':
    $fixed_price = 4.30;
    break;
}
```

Comment: am having the same problem after trying ur codes.....thanks anyway but ur suggestion didnt solve the question

Comment: anymore suggestion please?